# How to add shapes to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, pdf.js

I want to

- add rect shapes to each canvas which holds the current page pdf
- shapes can be n number of times in each page.

Problem

- Why is my shapes replacing the pdf too?
- not able to add rect shapes to each canvas which holds the current page pdf

Below is somewhat what i have tried. 
https://jsfiddle.net/goteL3hn/

Code:

```
// Adding a rectangle
jQuery(function($) {

    $("#addRectangle").click(function() {
    fCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("the-canvas", {
        selection: false
    });
        fCanvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
        }));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were rendering PDF in canvas `the-canvas` element, but while adding rect object you used the same element to create fabricjs canvas `the-canvas` element, so it cleared the canvas and drawn only rect object.

You need to render the pdf page data in fabricjs canvas top context and after image loaded add that as an image object in lower canvas element.

***DEMO***

```js
// If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

var pdfDoc = null,
  pageNum = 1,
  prevPageNum = 1,
  pageRendering = false,
  pageNumPending = null,
  scale = 0.8,
  fCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("the-canvas", {
    selection: false
  });
/**
 * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
 * @param num Page number.
 */
var pageHistory = {};

function renderPage(num) {
  pageHistory[prevPageNum] = fCanvas.toJSON();
  var jsonData = pageHistory[num];
  fCanvas.discardActiveObject(); //if you have any object selected, then it will deselect
  if (jsonData) {
    fCanvas.loadFromJSON(jsonData, function() {
      renderPdfData(num);
      fCanvas.renderAll.bind(fCanvas)
    });
  } else {
    pageHistory[num] = fCanvas.toJSON();
    fCanvas.clear();
    renderPdfData(num);
  }

}

function renderPdfData(num) {
  pageRendering = true;
  // Using promise to fetch the page
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    fCanvas.setDimensions({
      height: viewport.height,
      width: viewport.width
    })

    // Render PDF page into canvas context, use fabricjs top canvas element context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: fCanvas.contextTop,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

    // Wait for rendering to finish
    renderTask.promise.then(function() {
      pageRendering = false;
      var imageData = fCanvas.upperCanvasEl.toDataURL(); //create an image from top context and put it in lower canvas element
      fabric.Image.fromURL(imageData, function(img) {
        img.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          evented: false,
          selectable: false,
          excludeFromExport:true
        });
        fCanvas.add(img).sendToBack(img);
        fCanvas.clearContext(fCanvas.contextTop);
        if (pageNumPending !== null) {
          // New page rendering is pending
          renderPage(pageNumPending);
          pageNumPending = null;
        }
      });
    });
  });

  // Update page counters
  document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
}
/**
 * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
 * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
 */
function queueRenderPage(num) {
  if (pageRendering) {
    pageNumPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
}

/**
 * Displays previous page.
 */
function onPrevPage() {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  prevPageNum = pageNum;
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

/**
 * Displays next page.
 */
function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  prevPageNum = pageNum;
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

/**
 * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
 */
pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).then(function(pdfDoc_) {
  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
  document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

  // Initial/first page rendering
  renderPage(pageNum);
});

// Adding a rectangle
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#addRectangle").click(function() {
    fCanvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    }));
  });
});
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<h1>PDF.js Previous/Next example</h1>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="addRectangle" value="Add Signature">

  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
</div>

<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it seems when i do next or previous, its struck in the first page itself. Each page can have multiple rectangales. ....

Comment: @ShankarGuru only first page was showing because, it was coming on top of object stack everytime, check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it helped... is there a way to get the updated pdf back in byte array or base 64... i see that fCanvas only refers to current instance and pageHistory will only have visited ones... if i have update first and second page and can i get the first and second updated ones with remaining pages in byte array or base 64 back?

Comment: Tried, something but its not working as expected... https://jsfiddle.net/p6oacqmu/